# Реализация ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android, json, adapter, autocomplete

Доброе времени суток! Хочу реализовать AutoCompeleteView с подсказкой в виде выпадающего списка. Я беру данные с помощью JSON [Вот ссылка](http://www.p89742wj.bget.ru/get.php?term=s) Вроде все работает, но при нажатии на список я хочу получить еще id и currency из json. Как мне реализовать Class Adapter для этого?

```
public class SuggestionAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
public  String LOG_TAG = "my_log";
private List<String> suggestions;
private List<String> idsuggestions;//

public SuggestionAdapter(Context context, String filter) {
    super(context, R.layout.dropdown_item,R.id.textView11);//android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line
    suggestions = new ArrayList<String>();
    idsuggestions = new ArrayList<String>();//
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return suggestions.size();
}

@Override
public String getItem(int index) {
    return suggestions.get(index);
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    Filter myFilter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            JsonParse jp=new JsonParse();
            if (constraint != null) {
                // A class that queries a web API, parses the data and
                // returns an ArrayList<GoEuroGetSet>
                List<SuggestGetSet> new_suggestions =jp.getParseJsonWCF(constraint.toString());
                suggestions.clear();
                idsuggestions.clear();//
                for (int i=0;i<new_suggestions.size();i++) {
                    suggestions.add(new_suggestions.get(i).getName());
                    idsuggestions.add(new_suggestions.get(i).getId());//
                }
                // Now assign the values and count to the FilterResults
                // object
                filterResults.values = idsuggestions;//
                filterResults.values = suggestions;
                filterResults.count = suggestions.size();
                //Log.d(LOG_TAG, "id: " + idsuggestions);//
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "name: " + suggestions);//
            }
            return filterResults;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                                      FilterResults results) {
            if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
        }
    };

    return myFilter;
}
    }
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 5):

Сделайте адаптер типа `ArrayAdapter<SuggestGetSet>`. В конструктор передавайте уже готовый список, а в методе

```
getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
```

выводите название примерно так

```
((TextView)view).setText(list.getItem(position).getName)
```

Должно выглядеть примерно так

```java
    public class SuggestionAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SuggestGetSet> {

    private int viewResourceId;

    public SuggestionAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<SuggestGetSet> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        viewResourceId = textViewResourceId;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return suggestions.size();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(viewResourceId, null);
        }

        SuggestGetSet item = this.getItem(position);
        if (item != null) {
            TextView textView = (TextView) v;
            textView.setText(item.getName());
        }
        return v;
    }
}
```

После чего вешаете обработчик

```java
private OnItemClickListener listener = new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            SuggestGetSet item = (SuggestGetSet)parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);
            //some work
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно двумя способами:

1. Повесить **onClickListener** на список. В нём будет **position** нажатого элемента. По нему из адаптера можно получить данные методом списка **getItem(int position)**
2. Переопределить метод адаптера **getView** и в нём повесить **onClickListener** на View элемента. В метод **getView** также передаётся position, по которому из адаптера можно получить данные методом списка **getItem(int position)**

Comment: Спасибо. Все понял..